# geom_line with only one observation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

`bla <- data.frame(ID=1:5, phrase=c(1,1,2,2,2),word = c("Hello", "world!", "This", "is", "great."),  measurement1=c(runif(1), "NA", runif(2), "NA"), measurement2=runif(5))`

`bla$phrase` shows two phrases and each word has two values `measurement1` and `measurement2` is taken.

I want to plot each phrase seperately with (with`facet_wrap(~phrase)`?).
On the y-axis I want to have two lines; one showing `measurement1` and one showing `measurement2`.

I tried:

```
ggplot(bla) + geom_line(aes(reorder(word,ID), measurement1))+ geom_line(aes(reorder(word,ID), measurement2))+facet_wrap(~phrase)
```

That doesn't seem to do the trick and shows the warning:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
ggplot(bla) +
  geom_line(aes(reorder(word,ID), measurement1, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(reorder(word,ID), measurement2, group=1)) +
  facet_wrap(~phrase)
```

Producing this figure:

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I want, only that I would like to the words of the other phrase not to be displayed and NA to be removed, although that doesn't really make sense if the phrase consist only of two words (the last word never has a value for measurement1).

Comment: you could use any method to filter the NA (or rather "NA", since in your example `measurement1` has some values `"NA"` (the `string` `"NA"`, not the missing type `NA`!), for example, using `dplyr`:   `bla %>% 
      filter(!measurement1 %in% c("NA")) %>% 
      filter(!is.na(measurement1)) %>% 
    ggplot() +
      geom_line(aes(reorder(word,ID), measurement1, group=1)) +
      geom_line(aes(reorder(word,ID), measurement2, group=1)) +
      facet_wrap(~phrase)`. But yea, then you lose your observations for `phrase` 1